# The decoration of the new office block is more/most pleasing

Tags: adjectives, superlatives, comparative-degree, adjective-degrees

This sentence is from [Edgar Thorpe's
Objective English](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=tN5Q7ugFD34C&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=The%20decoration%20of%20the%20new%20office%20block%20is%20more/most%20pleasing.&source=bl&ots=8330iSly1b&sig=ACfU3U0ao0k76UXZ6dTIi55x9IvxCA_Sng&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjm2rPel6XrAhV94zgGHevECyEQ6AEwGXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20decoration%20of%20the%20new%20office%20block%20is%20more%2Fmost%20pleasing.&f=false).

As I know, we should use the comparative adjective to compare between two entities and superlative adjective to compare among three or more. But in this sentence, it is not clear to which ***'the new office block decoration'*** is being compared.

So is it fair to assume the speaker is comparing ***'the new office block decoration'*** with more than two entities and use superlative adjective and write:

> *The decoration of the new office block is **most** pleasing.*

Even so shouldn’t a superlative adjective be always preceded by **'the'**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most is not being used as a superlative in your sentence. It is being used as an adjective modifying 'pleasing' and meaning 'very'.

> Most
> formal
>
> very
>
> It was a most beautiful morning.

[Most (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/most)